# Where does the abbreviation こ, apparently meaning to be in a state, come from?

Tags: etymology, song-lyrics, suffixes, abbreviations, puns

I asked this question because I saw a pun in the song デンパラダイム where the producer tuned a lyric stating マッハ木っ端ミジンコ土っ管! I initially translated it as 'in the earthen pipes the negligibly tiny water fleas go at a fast speed" but there's also a word called 木っ端微塵 which is basically in smithereens justifying 木っ端's use as a prefix.
even though ミジンコ is in katakana,  knowing that 木っ端微塵 as a word existed I searched for a suffix called ko on Jisho.org to find out whether 木っ端微塵こ could be a clause and if 木っ端ミジンコ was a pun and found that it, こ, meant "being in a state" and, according to the site, was a suffix and abbreviation. I searched it up in Japanese typing ことは and こ 意味 and didn't find any definition matching the one on Jisho's, only finding definitions for words read こ. Does the word こ exist and what word or term does it come from?

Comment: checking jisho it says worthless thing or person as a prefix   researching koppamijin on jisho and mijin too

Comment: The word comes pretty transparently from 木っ端 "wood chips" + 微塵 "very fine pieces" — there's no such prefix こ in this word.

Comment: So does こ as a abbreviation and a suffix exist

Comment: What "こ" are you talking about then? The こ in 木っ端 is just how you read 木 in that word.

Comment: Here https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%20%23suf its in hiragana like にらめっこ

Comment: As it is, this question is still very difficult to understand. It is unclear what you consider こ an abbreviation of, and furthermore, it is unclear which こ you are referring to (from the start of 木っ端 or from the end of ミジンコ?) .

Comment: The end of ミジンコ、 but i didn't know how to clarify so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically [木っ端](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%9C%A8%E3%81%A3%E7%AB%AF) and [ミジンコ](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BE%AE%E5%A1%B5%E5%AD%90) are words on their own here. If you listen to the music video, you can recognize they are clearly sung as two separate words. So it makes no sense to discuss the meaning of コ in isolation.

[image]

Although 木っ端微塵 may be vaguely implied as something like a [*kakekotoba*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakekotoba), thinking about the meaning of コ is as meaningless as thinking about the meaning of ラダイム in デンパラダイム (which of course is a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of 電波 and パラダイム).

Comment: Im back and now that I think about it miniscule rice flour to mean koppamijin probably makes more sense and i searched gokko's yurai and a theory said it came from gokura